AOSP sync fails with RepoUnhandledExceptionError Number of processes must be at least 1
I am trying to sync AOSP code from code from Google but I am getting an error with little information about the cause of the problem.
$ repo init --partial-clone -b main -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -groups=all,-notdefault,-device,-darwin

repo has been initialized in /home/user/projects/aosp

$ repo sync
Fetching: 0, done in 0.007s
Fetching: 0,================================================================================
Repo command failed: RepoUnhandledExceptionError
    Number of processes must be at least 1


The problem is simply a single missing dash - in the groups option on the command line. It should be --groups or -g.
